# What stops me from using dependencies of dependencies in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a project that uses [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). OkHttp has [as one of its dependencies](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/e961166c4b11031b0b1fcb929e726170444e58fb/pom.xml#L47) the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library.

I want to use the Guava library in my app. When I include OkHttp in my `build.gradle`, Android Studio finds classes included in Guava and auto-imports them when I try to use them. My code compiles fine:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Integer> result = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

At runtime, the app crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap" on path: 
...     
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is easily solved by adding Guava explicitly to my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
```

I'm wondering what stops me from having access to this at runtime. I suspect I understand *why* (because libraries might change their dependencies, and this should be transparent to users of those libraries), but how is this implemented? Do dependencies get their own class loaders for their dependencies? Is it something in the Gradle build system restricting this? If this is the case, why does Android Studio/IntelliJ allow me to import from it - can't it tell that I won't have access to it at runtime?